# session when new tab in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have created a session when user login with value ="yes"
when the user logout the value get "no"
at the home page controller I check if the session equals to yes then open home page if else then open login page
the problem is if I opened a new tap or I wrote "localhost/myprojectname" at url in my browser it's open the log-in page

Log-in controller

```
        if($thePassword==$password){
            $this->session->set_userdata('log','yes');
            redirect(welcome);
        }
```

welcome controller (homepage)

```
if($this->session->userdata('log')=="yes"){
    $this->load->view('home');
}
else{
    redirect(LoginController);
}
```

Comment: where is your code of `session_start`

Comment: I don't think I need to start session in codeIgniter

Comment: i mean where do you load library `$this->load->library('session');`

Comment: in confiig/autoload.php

Comment: try this and check `echo "<pre>". print_r((array)$this->session, true) ."</pre>"`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of load session library in your controller's constructor as below:

`$this->load->library('session');`

Then

```
 if($thePassword==$password){
            $this->session->set_userdata('log',true);
            redirect(welcome);
        }
```

welcome controller (homepage)

```
if($this->session->has_userdata('log') && $this->session->userdata('log') == true){
    $this->load->view('home');
}
else{
    redirect(LoginController);
}
```

Comment: the same problem
 function logout(){
  $this->session->set_userdata('log',false);
  redirect(LoginController);
 }
I have this code in logout controller

Comment: first unset then set session to false.

Comment: `$this->session->unset_userdata('log');` then set it to false as above.

Comment: still have the same problem when I open a new tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132364/discussion-between-hikmat-sijapati-and-amado).